# C: How to capture special characters of the command line into a string

Tags: c

I would like to capture special characters such as \n from the command line into a C program.

For example, for the following program, if I run ./a.out "\nfoo\n" , I'd like to to print (newline) foo (newline) instead of  "\nfoo\n". How can I capture that in to a string?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    if(argc >1){
        char * s = strdup(argv[1]);
        printf("%s\n", s);
        free(s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: sorry, by (newline) foo (newline), I mean the acutal output is

foo

Currently,the output is literally "\nabc\n".(newlines are not printed because s captures "\n" 2 characters instead of the '\n' character). Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a new string, iterate through the old string adding characters to the new string.  if you ever see the `'\'` character, add a special character to the new string based on the next character in the old string.

Comment: Yes. To clarify, there is no library function that does it for you, so you'll have to do it yourself. For instance if you find a \ and then a `t` in the string, output a tab char. Things like that; you'll have to spell it out.

Answer (score 1):

C strings cannot grow dynamically, so you will need to allocate space for a new string and fill it with the desired contents. But to know how many characters will be required, you need to make a pass over `*s` first and count. Once you count the number of characters needed, you can `malloc` space for a new string, and start iterating over the old string and copying characters. Whenever you encounter one of your "special" characters, copy the appropriate replacement string into the new string.

Some code sketches (not tested; if you want to use any of this, you'll have to test and debug yourself):

```
char* replacement(char c) {
  if(c == '\n')
    return "(newline)";
  else if(c == '\t')
    return "(tab)";
  else
    return NULL;
}

int charactersNeeded(char* s) {
  int count = 0;
  char* r;
  while(*s != '\0') {
    r = replacement(*s);
    if(r != NULL)
      count += strlen(r);
    else
      count++;
    s++;
  }
  return count;
}

void copyString(char* s, char* t) {
  /* it is assumed that t points to a buffer of sufficient length
     to hold all the copied chars, as well as terminating null */
  char* r;
  do {
    r = replacement(*s);
    if(r != NULL) {
      strcpy(t, d);
      t += strlen(d)-1;
    } else *t = *s;
    s++;
    t++;
  } while(*s != '\0');
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, please see the Edit for clarification. The problem is that the program captures "\n" as 2 characters instead of the '\n' character.

Comment: I see. What you will need to do is still similar; first count the number of chars needed, allocate space, then copy. As you are copying chars, when you encounter a backslash, advance `s` by 1, and use the char you find to index into a lookup table, or use a function similar to `replacement` above (but with a return value of `char`).